# How to supplement the String class with a custom method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

In the Internet I found a bunch of identical articles and examples. But they did not help me...

I created the config/initializers/extension_default_classes.rb file:

```
class String
  def to_bool
    ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast(self)
  end
end

class NilClass
  def to_bool
    false
  end
end

class TrueClass
  def to_bool
    true
  end

  def to_i
    1
  end
end

class FalseClass
  def to_bool
    false
  end

  def to_i
    0
  end
end

class Integer
  def to_bool
    to_s.to_bool
  end
end
```

But as soon as I launch the application (in development or in production), I get an error:

> (erb):32:in `<main>': undefined method`to_bool' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)

This method (to_bool) is called in the config/settings/production(or development).yml files:

```
best_env: <%= ENV.fetch("BEST_ENV", false).to_bool %>
```

Tell me, please, how to correctly and reliably expand the default class?

Comment: Did you restart your app? Changes to the initializer won't be implemented without restarting your server.  Also, it may be that your ENV_VAR isn't a string but is nil/false.

Comment: Where is this `config/settings/production.yml` getting loaded? Seems like you are loading this file before the initializer runs. Please note `config/environment.rb` is loaded prior to initialization [Loading Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#loading-rails)

Comment: @bkunzi01Of course I restarted the application.

Comment: @engineersmnky https://github.com/railsconfig/config

Comment: In your "config/initializers/config.rb" file just add `require Rails.root.join('config','initializers','extension_default_classes')` to the very top. It seems like this file is just loading before your other initializer. Which makes sense since they are loaded in alphabetical order